# What is the function for typography api wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, function, api, plugins

Is someone know how to add this function wihtout a downloading a plugin ?
[image]

I prefer to use plugin but my teacher ask me to add this one without T.T

I find that one but it don't works :

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_textcolor' , array(
        'default'   => '#000000',
        'transport' => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'mytheme_new_section_name' , array(
        'title'      => __( 'Visible Section Name', 'mytheme' ),
        'priority'   => 30,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
        'label'      => __( 'Header Color', 'mytheme' ),
        'section'    => 'your_section_id',
        'settings'   => 'your_setting_id',
    ) ) );
    
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

Comment: On a side note, your teacher is right... don't use plugins to do everything you want or you'd end up with a site full of plugins that can bloat the code, slow the site down, make it difficult to maintain and and complicates fixing problems if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `add_panel` to register the panel. Additionally you have called `add_control` to add `WP_Customize_Color_Control` to a section you haven't defined.

The below code should work..
For more help you should consult the [wordpress customization api docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API).

```
function mytheme_customize_register($wp_customize){

    $wp_customize->add_panel('mytheme_new_panel',array(
        'title'=>__( 'Visible Panel Name', 'mytheme' ),
        'description'=> 'This is panel Description',
        'priority'=> 10,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_section('mytheme_new_section',array(
        'title'=>__( 'Visible Section Name', 'mytheme' ),
        'priority'=>10,
        'panel'=>'mytheme_new_panel',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('setting_demo',array(
        'defaule'=>'a',
    ));
    
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_textcolor' , array(
        'default'   => '#000000',
        'transport' => 'refresh',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('contrl_demo',array(
        'label'=>'Text',
        'type'=>'text',
        'section'=>'mytheme_new_section',
        'settings'=>'setting_demo',
    ));
}   
add_action('customize_register','mytheme_customize_register');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Great i got a new panel ! But nothing to customize fonts. Typography was used to set fonts.